# CUDA: Dependence of kernel performance on occupancy

Tags: performance, cuda

I am doing Finite Difference computation (Stencil Computation) on GPU (Fermi) using CUDA. When I tested my code using CUDA profiler, I found the occupany was `0.333`. After I ordered my computation and increased the occupany to `0.677`, the execution time of the kernel didn't decrease but increased. In other words, there was a decrease in performance when the occupany got increased by `1/3`.

My question is:

*Does the performance of the kernel depend on the computation irrespective of the occupancy?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "it depends", both on the characteristics of your workload and on how you define performance. Generally speaking, if your bottleneck is math throughput you're often fine with a lower occupancy (12.5%-33%), but if your bottleneck is memory then you usually want a higher occupancy (66% or higher). This is just a rule of thumb, not an absolute rule. Most kernels fall somewhere in the middle but there are exceptions at both extremes.

Occupancy is the maximum number of threads of your kernel that can be active at once (limited by register count per thread or other resources) divided by the maximum number of threads the GPU can have active when not limited by other resources. Active means the thread has hardware resources assigned and is available for scheduling, not that it has any instructions executing on a given clock cycle.

After issuing instruction *i* for a thread, the instruction *i+1* for that thread might not be able to run immediately, if it depends on the result of instruction *i*. If that instruction is a math instruction, the result will be available in a few clock cycles. If it's a memory load instruction, it might be 100s of cycles. Rather than waiting, the GPU will issue instructions from some other thread who's dependencies are satisfied.

So if you're mostly doing math, you only need a few (few in GPU terms; on a CPU it would be considered many) threads to hide the few cycles of latency from math instructions, so you can get away with low occupancy. But if you've got a lot of memory traffic, you need more threads to ensure that some of them are ready to execute on every cycle, since each one spends a lot of time "sleeping" waiting for memory operations to complete.

If the algorithmic changes you made to increase occupancy also increased the amount of work done on each thread, and if you already had enough threads to keep the GPU busy, then the change will just slow you down. Increasing occupancy only improves performance up to the point where you have enough threads to keep the GPU busy.

Answer (score 1):

Jesse Hall has already answered your question, so I will limit myself to complement his answer.

Occupancy is not the only figure of merit to take care of in order to maximize the algorithm performance, which most often coincide with the execution time. I suggest to take a look at the instructive GTC2010 presentation by Vasily Volkov:

[Better Performance at Lower Occupancy](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~volkov/volkov10-GTC.pdf)

Below, I'm providing a simple example, inspired by Part II of the above presentation.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 512

//#define DEBUG

/*******************/
/* iDivUp FUNCTION */
/*******************/
int iDivUp(int a, int b) { return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

/***********************************************/
/* MEMCPY1 - EACH THREAD COPIES ONE FLOAT ONLY */
/***********************************************/
__global__ void memcpy1(float *src, float *dst, unsigned int N)
{
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < N) {
        float a0 = src[tid];
        dst[tid] = a0;
    }
}

/*******************************************/
/* MEMCPY2 - EACH THREAD COPIES TWO FLOATS */
/*******************************************/
__global__ void memcpy2(float *src, float *dst, unsigned int N)
{
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * (2 * blockDim.x);

    if (tid < N) {
        float a0 = src[tid];
        float a1 = src[tid + blockDim.x];
        dst[tid] = a0;
        dst[tid + blockDim.x] = a1;
    }

}

/********************************************/
/* MEMCPY4 - EACH THREAD COPIES FOUR FLOATS */
/********************************************/
__global__ void memcpy4(float *src, float *dst, unsigned int N)
{
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * (4 * blockDim.x);

    if (tid < N) {

        float a0 = src[tid];
        float a1 = src[tid + blockDim.x];
        float a2 = src[tid + 2 * blockDim.x];
        float a3 = src[tid + 3 * blockDim.x];

        dst[tid] = a0;
        dst[tid + blockDim.x] = a1;
        dst[tid + 2 * blockDim.x] = a2;
        dst[tid + 3 * blockDim.x] = a3;

    }

}

/***********************************************/
/* MEMCPY4_2 - EACH THREAD COPIES FOUR FLOATS2 */
/***********************************************/
__global__ void memcpy4_2(float2 *src, float2 *dst, unsigned int N)
{
    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * (4 * blockDim.x);

    if (tid < N/2) {

        float2 a0 = src[tid];
        float2 a1 = src[tid + blockDim.x];
        float2 a2 = src[tid + 2 * blockDim.x];
        float2 a3 = src[tid + 3 * blockDim.x];

        dst[tid] = a0;
        dst[tid + blockDim.x] = a1;
        dst[tid + 2 * blockDim.x] = a2;
        dst[tid + 3 * blockDim.x] = a3;

    }

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
void main()
{
    const int N = 131072;

    const int N_iter = 20;

    // --- Setting host data and memory space for result
    float* h_vect   = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float* h_result = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) h_vect[i] = i;  

    // --- Setting device data and memory space for result
    float* d_src;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_src,  N*sizeof(float)));
    float* d_dest1; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_dest1, N*sizeof(float)));
    float* d_dest2; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_dest2, N*sizeof(float)));
    float* d_dest4; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_dest4, N*sizeof(float)));
    float* d_dest4_2; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_dest4_2, N*sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_src, h_vect, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Warmup
    for (int i=0; i<N_iter; i++) memcpy1<<<iDivUp(N,BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(d_src, d_dest1, N);

    // --- Creating events for timing
    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    /***********/
    /* MEMCPY1 */
    /***********/
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    for (int i=0; i<N_iter; i++) {
        memcpy1<<<iDivUp(N,BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(d_src, d_dest1, N);
#ifdef DEGUB
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif  
    }
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("GB/s = %f\n", (1.e-6)*(float)(N*N_iter*sizeof(float))/time);
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_result, d_dest1, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) if(h_result[i] != h_vect[i]) { printf("Error at i=%i! Host = %i; Device = %i\n", i, h_vect[i], h_result[i]); return; }

    /***********/
    /* MEMCPY2 */
    /***********/
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    for (int i=0; i<N_iter; i++) {
        memcpy2<<<iDivUp(N/2,BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(d_src, d_dest2, N);
#ifdef DEGUB
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif  
    }
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("GB/s = %f\n", (1.e-6)*(float)(N*N_iter*sizeof(float))/time);
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_result, d_dest2, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) if(h_result[i] != h_vect[i]) { printf("Error at i=%i! Host = %i; Device = %i\n", i, h_vect[i], h_result[i]); return; }

    /***********/
    /* MEMCPY4 */
    /***********/
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    for (int i=0; i<N_iter; i++) {
        memcpy4<<<iDivUp(N/4,BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(d_src, d_dest4, N);
#ifdef DEGUB
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif  
    }
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("GB/s = %f\n", (1.e-6)*(float)(N*N_iter*sizeof(float))/time);
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_result, d_dest4, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) if(h_result[i] != h_vect[i]) { printf("Error at i=%i! Host = %i; Device = %i\n", i, h_vect[i], h_result[i]); return; }

    /*************/
    /* MEMCPY4_2 */
    /*************/
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    for (int i=0; i<N_iter; i++) {
        memcpy4_2<<<iDivUp(N/8,BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>((float2*)d_src, (float2*)d_dest4_2, N);
#ifdef DEGUB
        gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif  
    }
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("GB/s = %f\n", (1.e-6)*(float)(N*N_iter*sizeof(float))/time);
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_result, d_dest4_2, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) if(h_result[i] != h_vect[i]) { printf("Error at i=%i! Host = %i; Device = %i\n", i, h_vect[i], h_result[i]); return; }

    cudaDeviceReset();

}
```

Below, the performance of the above code, when run on a GeForce GT540M and a Kepler K20c.

**BLOCKSIZE 32**

```
                GT540M            K20c              Tesla C2050
memcpy1          2.3GB/s   13%    28.1GB/s   18%    14.9GB/s   12%
memcpy2          4.4GB/s   13%    41.1GB/s   18%    24.8GB/s   13%
memcpy4          7.5GB/s   13%    54.8GB/s   18%    34.6GB/s   13%
memcpy4_2       11.2GB/2   14%    68.8GB/s   18%    44.0GB7s   14%
```

**BLOCKSIZE 64**

```
               GT540M             K20c              Tesla C2050
memcpy1         4.6GB/s    27%    44.1GB/s   36%    26.1GB/s   26%
memcpy2         8.1GB/s    27%    57.1GB/s   36%    35.7GB/s   26%
memcpy4        11.4GB/s    27%    63.2GB/s   36%    43.5GB/s   26%
memcpy4_2      12.6GB/s    27%    72.8GB/s   36%    49.7GB/s   27%
```

**BLOCKSIZE 128**

```
               GT540M             K20c              Tesla C2050
memcpy1         8.0GB/s    52%    60.6GB/s   78%    36.1GB/s   52%
memcpy2        11.6GB/2    52%    61.6GB/s   78%    44.8GB/s   52%
memcpy4        12.4GB/2    52%    62.2GB/s   78%    48.3GB/s   52%
memcpy4_2      12.5GB/s    52%    61.9GB/s   78%    49.5GB7s   52%
```

**BLOCKSIZE 256**

```
               GT540M             K20c              Tesla C2050
memcpy1        10.6GB/s    80%    61.2GB/s   74%    42.0GB/s   77%
memcpy2        12.3GB/s    80%    66.2GB/s   74%    48.2GB/s   77%
memcpy4        12.4GB/s    80%    66.4GB/s   74%    45.5GB/s   77%
memcpy4_2      12.6GB/s    70%    72.6GB/s   74%    50.8GB/s   77%
```

**BLOCKSIZE 512**

```
               GT540M             K20c              Tesla C2050
memcpy1        10.3GB/s    80%    54.5GB/s   75%    41.6GB/s   75%
memcpy2        12.2GB/s    80%    67.1GB/s   75%    47.7GB/s   75%
memcpy4        12.4GB/s    80%    67.9GB/s   75%    46.9GB/s   75%
memcpy4_2      12.5GB/s    55%    70.1GB/s   75%    48.3GB/s   75%
```

The above results show that you can have better performance, i.e. `12GB/s` for the GT540M case, with lower occupancy, i.e. `27%`, if you properly exploit *Instruction Level Parallelism (ILP)* by giving each thread more work to do in order to hide latency.